# Slice a dataframe by max value as an index

Tags: pandas, dataframe, slice

I currently have a dataframe of `strain` and `stress`, containing corresponding values. I want to slice the dataframe in a particular way - I want to find the max value in `stress`, and then take the next 5 rows of the dataframe. (I don't want to just find all the highest values in the column and sort by that.) Here is what I'm doing currently:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"strain": [1,2,4,6,2,4,7,4,8,3,4,7,3,3,6,4,7,4,3,2],
                    "stress": [0,0.2,0.5,0.8,0.7,1,0.7,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.4,0.2,0,-0.5,-0.8,-1,-0.8,-0.9,-0.7,-0.6]})

#Sort by stress values
new_df = df.copy()

new_df = new_df.sort_values(by = ['stress'], ascending = False)

new_df = new_df[0:5]
```

And this is my current output:

```
print(new_df)

   strain  stress
5       4     1.0
3       6     0.8
9       3     0.8
4       2     0.7
6       7     0.7
```

So my code is sorting by the highest values in stress. However, I want to main the row order behind the highest value in the column. This would be my expected output:

```
print(new_df)

strain  stress
5        4     1.0
6        7     0.7
7        4     0.6
8        8     0.7
9        3     0.8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`argmax`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.argmax.html?highlight=argmax#pandas.Series.argmax) to find the index of the maximum:

```
imax = df.stress.argmax()
df.iloc[imax:imax+5]
```

Result:

```
   strain  stress
5       4     1.0
6       7     0.7
7       4     0.6
8       8     0.7
9       3     0.8
```